# Loop through selected cells, check for borders and change colour

Tags: excel, vba, colors, border

I am creating a button for a toolbar to change colors from white background, black font, to white font black background within a selected area. (will be used for tables like P&L's, balance sheets etc in accounting).

But I also need some functionality in the button that looks through the cells that are selected, locates any existing borders and turns them white. Perhabs by having a boolean or something checking if the background color is black, and then turning existing borders white. I does not need to make any new borders, only invert the colors of existing ones.

This is what i've already have, but it just makes all borders white:

```
Dim Background As Boolean
Dim cel As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

With Selection.Borders

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
    If cel.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If

    If cel.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If

    Next cel
End With
```

Hope you're able to help me out :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can check the background color of a cell easily. What do you mean by locating the existing borders? Do you have some hidden borders (i.e. linestyle = xlNone)? If so I think setting their color to white shouldn't change the visibility.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Yes i've got the background check already which works fine, but I can only find a way to make all borders white. Guess my struggle is finding a way to looking through the selected cells, check if there is borders and colour them white.

The balance sheets etc would always be made on a white background, so the "existing borders" would be like this:
https://www.google.dk/search?q=p%26l&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=920&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkjerLvaDQAhUEhSwKHfoAAukQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=Tc86lvwlvv40gM%3A

There are no hidden borders, all visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the color to every border in the `Selection.Borders` collection because that's the `With` variable. Just set the color of `cel.Borders(xlEdgeTop)`

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set selectedRange = Application.Selection
For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
    With cel.Borders
        If .Item(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            .Item(xlEdgeTop).Color = vbWhite
        End If

        If .Item(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            .Item(xlEdgeBottom).Color = vbWhite
        End If
    End With
Next cel
```

You could also use two `With` blocks: `With cel.Borders(xlEdgeTop)` and `With cel.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)` and then just use `.LineStyle` and `.Color`. You could also skip the `With` block altogether because it really doesn't save much here (`cel.Borders` -> `.Item`).