# VBA Search Border cell and extract

Tags: excel, vba, border, extract, cell

I'm struggling with something. I need a vba for excell to search in all sheets if in my table there is a border cell and after that to go in other 5 tabels to extract the value.

[image]

and correlate with

[image]

(are 5 like this in total) and extract the value under them from all my sheets.
Can anyone to help me with this?

Comment: We're happy to help if you can show us what code you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't wrote any code for this because i don't know from where to start. I'm new on this and this is too complex for my level.

Comment: You will have to start by going step by step, first writing some code to get the `UsedRange` [property](https://excelchamps.com/vba/usedrange/) of the worksheet and then looping through that range to discover [which cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40554377/4717755) have the [borders you're looking for](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/cells/Lesson4.htm). After that, you can add the next stage of code to copy the values you want.

Comment: I will try this to see if i can do it! Thank you